# How do we mutate a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string t2 and I want to mutate this string based on the below `if` condition . I tried `.replace` but it doesnt work.

```
t2 = "<li class='coded_true'>"+tp_info.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip+"</li>"

if (tp_info.attributes["ITcoded"]== "true")
                t2= t2.replace(t2,"<li class='coded_true ITcoded_true'>"+tp_info.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip+"</li>");
                end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Your snippet isn't valid JavaScript, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Just reassign it the result of the replacement. A string is a primitive. It isn't mutable.

Comment: @user2569524 So you're looking for a way to assign a new value to `t2`, is that correct?

Comment: Or do you want to replace a portion of `t2` with another string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `.replace()` to substitute the entire string:

```
t2 = t2.replace(t2, ...);
```

At that point, you can just assign the replacement directly:

```
t2 = "<li class='coded_true ITcoded_true'>"+tp_info.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip+"</li>";
```

Though, since the difference between them is in the `class` names, you might consider trying to determine those ahead of time and build the markup string afterwards.

```
var t2_class = ['coded_true'];

if (tp_info.attributes["ITcoded"] == "true") {
    t2_class.push('ITcoded_true');
}

var t2 = "<li class='" + t2_class.join(' ') + "'>"+tp_info.elements["info"].cdatas.join.strip+"</li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do `t2.replace(t2, ...` ?  This should always replace the entire string by the definition of the replace function because your search term is the string itself:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Executing the statement `t2.replace(t2, foo)` will produce a result of `foo`, but will not otherwise change the script environment in any way. `t2` will remain the same.

Comment: Exactly... so why not just assign foo to t2? t2 = t2.replace(t2, foo) and t2 = foo should be equivalent.

Comment: "Did you mean to do `t2.replace(t2, ...`". This might just be me misreading what you're saying, but it sounded like you were suggesting the OP should use this. You didn't mention direct assignment at all.

Comment: Oh, I see how that could be misleading.  I thought the `t2` in that position was a mistake and he was actually trying to replace something in the string, not the entire string.

Comment: I actually still suspect that's what the OP might be trying to do. Until he/she clarifies though, there's no way to tell.